# A way to improve performance of the following query (update table)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This question is related to a question I published a while ago, and can be found here: [Update values of database with values that are already in DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392243/update-values-of-database-with-values-that-are-already-in-db) .

I've the following situation:  A table that stores data from different sensors (I've a total of 8 sensors).  Each row of the table has the following structure:

> SensorID --- TimestampMS --- RawData --- Data

So, for example, for a temperature sensor called TEMPSensor1 I have the following:

> TEMPSensor1 --- 1000 --- 200 --- 2 
>  TEMPSensor1 --- 2000 --- 220 --- 2.2

And so on, for each sensor (in total I've 8).  I've some problems reading the data, and there are rows which data "is not correct".  Precisely when the rawdata field is 65535, I should update that particular row.  And what I would like to do is put the next value (in time) to that "corrupted data".  So, if we have this:

> TEMPSensor1 --- 1000 --- 200 --- 2 
>  TEMPSensor1 --- 2000 --- 220 --- 2.2  
>     TEMPSensor1 --- 3000 --- 65535 --- 655.35 
>  TEMPSensor1 --- 4000 --- 240 --- 2.4

After doing the Update, the content of the table should be changed to:

> TEMPSensor1 --- 1000 --- 200 --- 2 
>  TEMPSensor1 --- 2000 --- 220 --- 2.2  
>     TEMPSensor1 --- 3000 --- 240 --- 2.4 
>  TEMPSensor1 --- 4000 --- 240 --- 2.4

I've ended up doing the following:

```
UPDATE externalsensor es1
INNER JOIN externalsensor es2 ON es1.sensorid = es2.sensorid AND (es2.timestampms - es1.timestampms) > 60000 AND (es2.timestampms - es1.timestampms) < 120000  AND es1.rawdata <> 65535
SET es1.rawdata = es2.rawdata, es1.data = es2.data
WHERE es1.rawdata = 65535
```

Because I know that between two reads from a sensor there are between 60000 and 120000 ms.  However, if I have two following "corrupted" readings, that won't work.  Can anyone suggest a way to do this more efficiently, with no use of subquery selects, but JOINS?  My idea would be to have a JOIN that gives you all the possible values for that sensor after its timestampms, and just get the first one, but I don't know how I can limit that JOIN result.

Appreciate.

Comment: Why don't you use JNK's solution from that question? It seems to be working when there are 2 or more consecutive corrupted readings.

Comment: Or Dems's solution. I think both will work with only minor adjustment.

Comment: @ypercube:  I would like to avoid using a subquery because it seems to be the reason of having a bad performance (correlated behavior) in MYSQL.

Comment: Are all timestamps unique for every sensor?

Comment: @Andriy: Yes, all timestampms unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A completely different approach, using a procedure that runs through the whole table (in descending time order for every sensor):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE updateMyTable()
BEGIN
  SET @dummy := -9999 ;
  SET @dummy2 := -9999 ;
  SET @sensor := -999 ;

  UPDATE myTable m
    JOIN 
    ( SELECT n.SensorID
           , n.TimestampMS
           , @d := (n.RawData = 65535) AND (@sensor = n.SensorID) AS problem
           , @dummy  := IF(@d, @dummy, n.RawData) as goodRawData
           , @dummy2 := IF(@d, @dummy2, n.Data) as goodData
           , @sensor := n.SensorID AS previous
      FROM myTable n
      ORDER BY n.SensorID
             , n.TimeStampMS DESC
    ) AS upd
    ON m.SensorID = upd.SensorID
      AND m.TimeStampMS = upd.TimeStampMS
  SET m.RawData = upd.goodRawData
    , m.Data = upd.goodData
  WHERE upd.problem
  ;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: It's a nice feature of MySQL's, the one that allows you to retrieve columns along with assigning variables. With regard to the OP's problem this feature seems a more or less equivalently powerful substitute for ranking functions in SQL Server, the thing I might probably have employed if I were to solve the problem in SQL Server.

Comment: Well, even if I can't 'speak' MySQL very well, I think I can comprehend this solution well enough to be able to conclude that it should work. The algorithm seems clear and correct, so it's a +1 from me. I hope the OP will leave a feedback, I'm interested to know if it's all right.

Comment: This worked SUPER well and fast.  Appreciate all the help and feedback Andriy and ypercube.

Comment: @Nobita: Thanks for letting us know what has ultimately worked for you. And I'm particularly satisfied with being confirmed in my assumption that this MySQL-specific trick is indeed a very efficient tool.

Comment: Thnx too, for letting us know.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution without correlated subqueries, but with a triangular join (not sure which is worse):

```
UPDATE externalsensor bad

  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      es1.SensorID,
      es1.TimestampMS,
      MIN(es2.TimestampMS) AS NextGoodTimestamp
    FROM externalsensor es1
      INNER JOIN externalsensor es2
        ON es1.SensorID = es2.SensorID AND
           es1.TimestampMS < es2.TimestampMS
    WHERE es1.RawData = 65535
      AND es2.RawData <> 65535
    GROUP BY
      es1.SensorID,
      es1.TimestampMS
  ) link ON bad.SensorID = link.SensorID AND
            bad.TimestampMS = link.TimestampMS

  INNER JOIN externalsensor good
    ON link.SensorID = good.SensorID AND
       link.NextGoodTimestamp = good.TimestampMS

SET
  bad.RawData = good.RawData,
  bad.Data = good.Data
```

It is assumed that the timestamps are unique within a single sensor group.

Comment: @Andriy: I'm going to try it out once I get back to work.  I might have problems having a select while doing an update to the same table in Mysql though.

Comment: @ypercube: That's a great thing to know, thanks! Still, it may behave differently with a large table, which unfortunately I cannot test. So it's up to Nobita.

Comment: @Andriy:  It does.  Took quite a lot to update a single sensor...But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Nobita: what indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: @Nobita: I'm asking about indexes becasue I think that most if not all solutions, including the correlated subqueries ones (you have from previous question) would have better performace if a (sensorId, timestamp) index existed in your table.

Comment: @ypercube:  I've these:
KEY `sensorid` (`sensorid`,`rawdata`,`timestampms`),
  KEY `sensorid_2` (`sensorid`,`timestampms`,`rawdata`)

Comment: @Nobita: Aren't the combinations of (`sensorid`, `timestampms`) unique?

Comment: @Andriy.  They are, but not formally.  There is not a key defined for this.

Comment: @Nobita: I guess that @Andriy: means that the second index could be "lowered" to `(sensorid,timestampms)`. Having a complex (3-level or more) index can sometimes cause inserting and updating the table being slower. (I don't know about the first index, I guess you have some queries that use it but perhaps that could be "lowered" to 2 levels too).

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to use Dems solution from the previous question, here's a "solution" with JOIN's:

```
UPDATE myTable m
  JOIN myTable n
    ON m.SensorID = n.SensorID
      AND n.RawData <> 65535
      AND m.TimestampMS < n.TimestampMS
  JOIN myTable q
    ON n.SensorID = q.SensorID
      AND q.RawData <> 65535
      AND n.TimestampMS <= q.TimestampMS
SET
  m.RawData = n.RawData,
  m.Data = n.Data
WHERE
   m.RawData = 65535
;
```

---

EDIT

My query above is wrong, dead wrong. It appears to be working in my test db but the logic is flawed. I'll explain below.

Why the above query works fine but is dead wrong:

First, why it's wrong.

Because it will not return one row for every (sensorID, bad timestamp) combination but many rows. If `m` (`m.TimestampMS`) is the bad timestamp we want to find, it will return all combinations of that bad timetsamp and later good timestamps `n` and `q` with `n.TimestampMS <= q.TimestampMS`. It would be a correct query if it found the MINIMUM of these `n` timestamps.

Now, how come it actually works all right in my test db?

I think it's because MySQL, when it comes to use the `SET ...` and has a lot of options (rows) it just uses first option. But lucky me, I added the test rows in increasing timestamp order so they were saved in that order in the db, and (again) lucky me, this is how the query plan is scheduled (I presume).

Even this query works in my test db:

```
UPDATE myTable m
  JOIN myTable n
    ON m.SensorID = n.SensorID
      AND n.RawData <> 65535
      AND m.TimestampMS < n.TimestampMS
SET
  m.RawData = n.RawData,
  m.Data = n.Data
WHERE
   m.RawData = 65535
;
```

while being flawed for the same reasons.

Comment: @ypercube: I would like to avoid using a subquery because it seems to be the reason of having a bad performance (correlated behavior) in MYSQL

Comment: @Nobita: Bad performance can be caused by lack of proper indexes. I suggest you check all possible solutions, by testing performance and examining their plan execution.

Comment: @ypercube:  I would like to know, how that would get the first "correct" next row for a given ID.  I fail to see how those two JOINs do that?

Comment: @Nobita: The first correct comes from `n.TimestampMS <= q.TimestampMS`. Tables n and q have rows with bigger timestamps than table m: `m.TimestampMS < n.TimestampMS`

Comment: @Nobita: I was dead wrong in my previous comment. And dead wrong my query is! I'll edit my answer with details.

Comment: @ypercube: Yes.  That's basically the problem I was having.  How do you get just the first row of a JOIN?  That's why I delimited between 60.000 and 120.000 ms, because I know that's the interval of reading for each sensor...